# Swap real and imaginary part of a complex number

Tags: notation, complex-numbers

Say I have some complex number $z=a+ib$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. Now I want to "swap" its real and imaginary parts, i.e. I want to get $\tilde{z}=b+ia$.

While I figure that the appropriate mapping would be $\tilde{z}=-i\overline{ z }$, (where $\overline{z}$ denoting the complex conjugate of $z$), I keep wondering whether there is some standard notation/function for this. All of $z^\dagger, z^*,\hat{z}$ and the like usually have some other meaning to my knowledge.

Comment: I know of no such notation. And $i\overline{z}$ is simple enough that the only reason to have such a notation would be when it is _often_ used, which, afaik, it isn't.

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed, I overlooked that $i\overline{z}$ was sufficient and that indeed doesn't seem to require some new (even shorter) notation. Thanks!